# UICollectionView with Cells that contain UIWebViews dynamic resize

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm searching for a way to dynamically resize the `UICollectionViewCell`s in a `UICollectionView`. These cells contain a UIWebView that is populated with dynamic HTML content. Thus I don't know the height of the webview before.

I tried to hook into the `func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)` function and resize them dynamically but this destroyed the entire layout. Because the cells grew into each other.

I've to build for iOS 7.1

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Did you figure out a good solution for this? I am having the same issue. I tried following a few approaches but I believe there is no one standard approach. The iOS-JavaScript bridge is something I need to look into.

Comment: Hi @Chris did You find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create height constraint to the UIWebView and add the constraint as outlet to your UICollectionViewCell.

Overload the method webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Fit web content size.
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    CGRect oldFrame = frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    webView.frame = oldFrame;

    // Set content web view height constraint to new content size.
    self.contentWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = fittingSize.height;
}
```

Now when the webView height constraint change the cell height should change if you set the constraint correctly.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I have done that, but all cells are of variable heights and when I scroll the list, reused cells take time to readjust to their new size.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

1. Create an array to store the heights of the cells by index `heightArray: [CGFloat]`
2. When `func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)` returns,  you're able to determine the cell's height. Save this height to your array using the cell's index `heightArray[indexPath.row] = height`
3. Call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`. This will force the table to recalculate the heights of the cell by calling `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
   heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`
4. Implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
   heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` to return the height from your given `heightArray`

That's the general outline for having dynamic cell heights in a UITableView. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks... But I'm searching for `UICollectionView` and *not* `UITableView`. I think a collection view doesn't have a `heightFor...` method?